# Number of ways a process can communicate with another process in any OS

Tags: unix

What are the total number of ways that 2 processes  can intercommunicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. file
2. o/s pipe
3. socket
4. shared memory
5. semaphores, mutexes, spinlocks, etc.
6. program argument and exit value
7. signals
8. operating system specific features

Comment: Please throw some light on "operating system specific features" say if we are talking about windows. I mean does different OS radically differ from each other because 1-6 are found in all flavors of UNIX.

Comment: No unique features of windows come to mind which pertain to #7; I was thinking of more original operating systems like pSoS and RTTS which have a mailbox mechanism which is effectively a shared memory plus a pipe where the pipe sequentializes pointers to shared memory.

Comment: You can add signals (eg SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2) to the list.